# how to get click or tab select a panel?

Tags: jquery

how to get a click or a tab to select either north, west, or center panel?
This is tab code works but don't know how to integrate it with a click-panel code

**JAVASCRIPT :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var divs = ["north", "west", "center"];
    var startIndex = 0;
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 9) {
            $("div").css("border", "");
            $("#" + divs[startIndex]).css("border", "4px solid gray");
            if(divs[startIndex] == "north"){
                alert("north");
            }else if(divs[startIndex] == "west"){
                alert("west");
            }else{
                alert("center");
            }

            startIndex++;

            if(startIndex === divs.length) {
                startIndex = 0;
            }                   
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

**HTML :**

```
<div id="north"><textarea></textarea></div>
<div id="west"><textarea></textarea></div>
<div id="center"><textarea></textarea></div>
```

Comment: I don't understand, can you clarify the question? What's a _click-panel_ code?

Comment: I tab select between the panels, now I would like click to select a panel along with tab selecting a panel.

Comment: Still, don't get it? What's a _panel_? A `<textarea>`? A `<div>`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant each div is used as a panel for the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the same functionality to happen when you click as when you tab you want something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         var divs = ["north", "west", "center"];
         var startIndex = 0;
         var fn =   function (e) {
                 $("div").css("border", "");
                 $("#" + divs[startIndex]).css("border", "4px solid gray");

                 if(divs[startIndex] == "north") {
                     console.log("north");
                  } else if(divs[startIndex] == "west") {
                     console.log("west");
                  }else {
                     console.log("center");
                  }
              startIndex++;
              if(startIndex === divs.length) {
                  startIndex = 0;
              }    
         };
         $(document).keydown(function(e) {
             if (e.which == 9) {
              fn();                     
          }
          return false;
         }).click(function() {
             //any logic like the 'tab' check above
             fn();
         });
});​
```

There is a common function that is used to do the background highlighting and such that is invoked from either the `keydown` or the `click` handle.

Demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/slace/D39P3/